# XCode copies blank database when doing build

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I've noticed that even though I placed my sqlite3 database in the "resources" folder, and even though I checked the "Copy file" box, when I do a build, XCode creates an empty database toi the application folder it's building...so it's FINDING the database, and OPENING it, but there's nothing IN  it, so when I do a sqlite3_prepare_v2, I get a SQLITE_ERROR...

Help!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial helps you setup an SQL database that will be included with your program:
[SQLite To Do Tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)

That might help you find something you've missed. I'm assuming that since you're getting SQLITE_ERROR you've correctly included the libsqlite3.0.dylib. Are you sure that your database file is valid and was created correctly?

Comment: Yes... the database was working before, and suddenly stopped working... I've checked the original database that I'm dropping in the Resources folder, and it's 31M.  But, when I do a build, XCode creates a database by the same name in the application folder that it's building, but is not copying the contents.  The file is there, but it's got 0k bytes.

Any ideas?